# Hide my iframe, nobody can see

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe

This is my index.php

```
$way = 'http://EXAM.COM'; 

$fd = @file($way); 

if ($fd !== false) 

if (isset($fd[0])) 

echo(' <iframe src="'.$fd[0].'" width="100" height="100" style="position:absolute;left:-1px;"></iframe> ');
```

So every one come to my website will load this iframe, and Ctrl+U will see:

```
<iframe width='100' scrolling='no' height='100' frameborder='500' src='http://URL-FROM-EXAM.com'>
```

How can I hide my iframe, including from inspect element/view source?

Comment: you can never hide the source code of your application

Comment: If you don't want someone to see the code your server is serving, don't serve it. You can't send an iframe and expect the user to not know that there was an iframe in your response.

Comment: The only way to "hide" what your server is serving would be to obfuscate the html/javascript. But browsers (and anti-viruses :)) have gotten pretty good at de-obfuscate both of them.

Comment: Thanks Nepho, how i can obfuscate my php iframe code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide client side code, which HTML is. You can minify it, but the people who watch your code probably know how to prettify it.

So in short: **you can't**.

Comment: I was try to encode php code, but html iframe code will show

Answer (score 0):

use jquery in head

$('body').load('yoururl');

Answer (score 0):

The only practical reason I can see for wanting to hide your iframe is to actually hide the `http://URL-FROM-EXAM.com`, right? People who know what page source code is and know how to read it, will most likely know how to also trace network/HTTP calls from your browser. Most modern browsers are well equipped at doing that so its a real no-brainer.

Perhaps you need to look at this problem backwards - don't hide your iframes, URLs or what not, but protect your resources instead. That being said, the fact that your resource is loaded in the iframe, pretty much means that it is also available for anyone to see and inspect. Have you thought about securing your application behind some sort of authentication mechanism?

Welcome to the *World Wide Web*!